# When is Playwright's "waitForSelector" necessary?

Tags: playwright

Im honestly curious why this method exists? Playwright auto-waits for things to be visible or loaded typically. So why would we ever need to call `page.waitForSelector("locator")`?

I understand if we are waiting for a specific state, but I see a lot of example code using this method thrown around randomly......but I can't quite figure out why it would be necessary in a normal circumstance?

Comment: What example code, specifically? It's largely an artifact of Puppeteer, so most of the time you will be using locators. AFAIK it's basically shorthand for `page.locator("foo").waitFor()`, like `page.textContent("foo")` is shorthand for `page.locator("foo").textContent()`, more or less.

Comment: Good Practices are never necessary - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76103866

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs for `waitForSelector`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector), it's never necessary:

> Playwright automatically waits for element to be ready before performing an action. Using [Locator](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator) objects and web-first assertions makes the code wait-for-selector-free.

Playwright started out largely as a rewrite of Puppeteer for Microsoft. Puppeteer relies on `page.$`, `page.$eval`, `page.waitForSelector` and ElementHandles to do most of its work. These are lower-level, single-purpose functions could be thought of as the primitive building blocks of browser automation. Playwright has diverged, and at the current time has deprecated or discouraged most of the Puppeteer-inherited API in favor of locators.

Locators have auto-waiting and strictness capabilities and operate at a higher level than the Puppeteer-style operations. Locators improve readability and reliability by combining waits and actions (like `.click()`, `.type()`, `.textContent()`, `.inputValue()`, `.evaluate()`, `.count()`, `.waitFor()`, etc) into a single atomic step. When an action is fired on a locator, Playwright always waits and re-selects the freshest element from the DOM, helping to avoid stale handles and race conditions.

Almost always, when you're waiting for a selector to exist, you'll want to take an action on it, so although you can use `page.locator("foo").waitFor()` as a locator-first translation of `page.waitForSelector("foo")`, you'll usually use `page.locator("foo").click()` or another, more specific action than `.waitFor()`. In other words, `.click()` and all other actions basically have a `.waitFor()` baked into them.

You haven't shown any examples, so this is rather hand-wavey and general, but I'd guess that the examples are likely outdated and can be re-written with equivalent locators, as with basically all of the deprecated/discouraged shorthand locators like `page.textContent()`, `page.click()`, `page.inputValue()` (etc).

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite an opinion-based question. But one example would be having a Wizard-type form (a page with steps). Each step has a "Next" button.
You might want to wait for a selector to know that you moved from one step to another. If you don't, you might end up clicking the "Next" button on one step twice because you didn't wait for the next step to show up.

Comment: I guess that make sense, I suppose they want to use maybe waitforUrl instead but in your example it might be a SPA that does that.

Answer (score 2):

> #### Good Practices are never necessary
>
> Using `waitForSelector` function in   certain situations ***builds
> stability in your tests*** as it allows you to explicitly wait for the
> presence of a specific element on a page before proceeding with
> further actions like on page loads.

**While Playwright does provide automatic waiting behavior, there are
scenarios where explicit waiting becomes crucial for stability.**

Here is one scenario which I personally encountered where using`waitForSelector` makes sense.

---

##### Example:

[image]

#### To wait for spinner to disappear

as one of many use cases to verify the [state](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector) of an object to be attached/visible/hidden/detached from DOM before moving on to the actual test steps which works on 'other objects' once page loads or after save etc.

> This builds more stability in long transactional flows

like an online  order where many tabs/pages load/unload in single E2E test.

> I think it is important to note that waitForSelector() will throw an
> error if the element is not found within the specified timeout.
> Therefore, it is important to choose a timeout that is long enough for
> the element to appear, but not so long that your test becomes slow and
> unreliable.

Reference:https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2202