# c# selenium waiting for background requests to finish

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation

on the page where I write test automation, javascript is running intensively. React is used as the infrastructure. For example, pagination works with javascript, and when I go to the next page, the page loads after waiting for a while. In such a scenario, my automation works and gives an error because it cannot find the element I expect. What can I do to make the automation work correctly in such scenarios? I don't want to use the Thread.sleep function.

It works after waiting 1 second with Thread.sleep, but it is an amateurish method.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have enough information to provide a good answer. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro], which includes all relevant C# code and a representative amount of HTML. Links to the page you are automating are also welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue faced in Test automation and can be resolved in various ways:

1. If you are using Selenium or any automation tool other than Playwright, you can consider multiple options. You can wait for the DOM to completely load, you can wait for a particular web element to be present using WebDriverWait. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)
2. If you are using Playwright, you can use defined methods for the page to be completely loaded and background methods to die using methods like page.waitForLoadState() and waiting for elements to be present using page.waitForSelector(). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876841/playwright-wait-for-page-to-completely-load-and-xhr-ajax-calls-complete) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093014/when-is-playwrights-waitforselector-necessary/76103866#76103866)

I would strongly suggest researching more about how to build stable and robust test automation frameworks.

Comment: I saw this topics but did not work for me. I do not use playwright. Page use react and javascript not jquery.